# Why is this code not constant-space?

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm learning Haskell currently (being a programmer by trade, but this is my first attempt at a functional language).

I want to write a function that scans a list and returns both the minimum and maximum element of that list. Sort of what the Prelude functions `minimum` and `maximum` do, but both at the same time. I've come up with the following code:

```
import Data.List

-- Declaration of rand

minMax :: [Int] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
minMax []   = Nothing
minMax (x:xs) = Just (foldl' f (x, x) xs)
                where
                  f (a, b) c = (if c < a then c else a, if c > b then c else b)
```

`rand` is a function that generates an infinite list of numbers.
The thing is that when I append the following `main` function:

```
main = print $ minMax $ take 1000000 $ rand 7666532
```

compile and run all this with profiling, it shows me it uses over 200 MB of memory, so it's definitely not a constant-space function (which I'd like it to be).

The question is why and what should I change to fix it. As I understand `foldl'` folds the list from left (same way it's generated) and is not lazy, so I don't see why the memory usage is so high. I'm pretty sure it's the `minMax` function that is incorrect, as simply printing the said list, using

```
main = print $ take 1000000 $ rand 7666532
```

gives me 1MB usage, something that I understand and expect.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full code, including the definition of `rand`. Using a strict left fold doesn't force the evaluation of the elements of the pair, here, because your accumulator is already in weak head normal form, and tuples are lazy.

Comment: Either pepper your code with `seq`, or define a strict pair datatype: `data Pair a b = Pair !a !b` and use it in place of plain old `(a,b)`.

Comment: I'd like to mention [the `foldl` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.1.1/docs/Control-Foldl.html) which abstracts combining folds like this efficiently, in fact one of the examples given is: `L.fold ((,) <$> L.minimum <*> L.maximum) [1..10000000]`

Comment: obligatory: make sure you're compiling with optimizations

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that `foldl'` forces the accumulator to *weak* head normal form. Since the accumulator is a tuple it does **not** force the evaluation of the two elements of the tuple.

If you explicitly force the two elements you get a constant-space function:

```
f (a, b) c = a `seq` b `seq` (if c < a then c else a, if c > b then c else b)
```

In your original program you are building a tuple of the kind: `(<thunk>, <thunk>)` and *every time `f` is applied you simply build a tuple with bigger and bigger thunks*. When finally this is consumed by `print` the call to `show` forces the full evaluation of the tuple and all the comparisons are made at that point.

Using `seq` you instead force `f` to evaluate the comparison at that moment, and thus the thunks contained in the accumulator are evaluated before performing the comparison. Hence the result is that the thunks stored in the accumulator have constant size.

What `foldl'` does is simply avoid building the thunk: `f (f (f ...) y) x`.

An alternative solution, as suggested by Jubobs, to avoid explicitly using `seq` is to use a data type that has strict fields:

```
data Pair a b = Pair !a !b
    deriving Show
```

And so the code would become:

```
minMax :: [Int] -> Maybe (Pair Int Int)
minMax []   = Nothing
minMax (x:xs) = Just (foldl' f (Pair x x) xs)
                where
                  f (Pair a b) c = Pair (if c < a then c else a) (if c > b then c else b)
```

This avoids thunks altogether.

Comment: Wait... but you're still storing thunks there. Are you not?

Comment: @Jubobs Ah yeah. The accumulator is passed as `(if .., if ..)`. However it *is* constant space (at each call to `f` the thunk is evaluated, so they are constant in size.

Comment: GHC will almost certainly avoid creating thunks once you've made sure the function is strict enough, as long as you're compiling with optimizations enabled (`-O` or `-O2`).

Answer (score 12):

The `seq` function which is used in `foldl'` essentially forces its first argument to be evaluated down to WHNF (Weak Head Normal Form).

As explained [here](https://hackhands.com/lazy-evaluation-works-haskell/), WHNF evaluation stops once you each the application of a **constructor**. `(a, b)` is therefore always in WHNF, even if `a` and `b` are thunks since you're hitting the Tuple constructor `(,)` before getting to `a` and `b`.

As a result, this space leaks despite the use of `foldl'`:

```
foldl' (\ (a, b) x -> (a + x, b + x)) (0, 1) [1..1000000]
```

but this doesn't:

```
foldl' (\ (a, b) x -> a `seq` b `seq` (a + x, b + x)) (0, 1) [1..10000000]
```

It's also sometimes convenient to use the `-XBangPatterns` extension to write this:

```
foldl' (\ (!a, !b) x -> (a + x, b + x)) (0, 1) [1..10000000]
```

Comment: Great link, gave me some better understanding of what is going on under the hood. And now I'm having a hard time deciding which answer to accept... I wish I could do both.